# How to interpret a discrete set raised to a power?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I suddenly got confused on how to interpret a discrete set raised to a power and could not find a definite answer.

Is it correct that when we take an integer power of a discrete set we think of it as increasing the dimension of the set, where each dimension can take on a value in the base set? i.e: $\{x,y\}^2 = \{(x,x), (x,y), (y,y), (y,x)\}$?

Comment: That's essentially right.

Comment: this is nothing to do with any notion of discreetness. The notation you have encounted is a shorthand for the product set $\{x,y\} \times \{x,y\}$

Comment: Thank you both. That {x,y}^2 is a shorthand notation for the product set perfectly clarifies the notation for me. That's the answer I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: For reference, $\times$ in this context you will see written in literature as the "[cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)."  The [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) implies that $|A\times B|=|A|\times |B|$ so here we have $\{x,y\}^n$ has $2^n$ elements.

Comment: It is worth also pointing out the notation $B^A$ where $B$ and $A$ are both sets which denotes the number of functions from $A$ to $B$.  You could have read your notation as $\{x,y\}^{[2]}$ which would have given effectively the same result.  The notation I introduce is useful in that we have $|B^A|=|B|^{|A|}$ and that we can freely switch between a number $n$ and the set $[n]$ (*which is the prototypical $n$-element set $\{0,1,2,3,\dots,n-1\}$ or $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$ depending on author*) without drastically changing the meaning of things here.

Comment: Also, if you run into the notation $B^A$ where $A$ and $B$ are both set this is the collection of all functions from $A$ to $B$. Here we can interpret it as the collection of all functions from a set of two elements to $\{x,y\}$. $(x,x)$ and $(y,y)$ are constant functions that are neither injective or surjective, while $(x,y)$ and $(y,x)$ are bijections.